# Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy, remove actives when leaving area

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using scrollspy from twitter bootstrap and it keeps nav elements selected after leaving an section if it doesn't trigger another section.

Anyone know if there's a way to clear the selections, once it leaves the selected area and doesn't trigger another item?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't too keen on patching twitter bootstrap because of the long term ramifications when updating bootstrap versions. I ended up adding hidden nav elements to represent the areas where I didn't want scrollspy to highlight a nav element.

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="hidden">
    <%= link_to "Top", '#top' %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "Features", '#features' %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "Gift Collections", '#gift-collections' %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "Pricing", '#pricing' %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and found this: https://gist.github.com/kirov/9482666

These are the changes you need to add:

```
    if (scrollTop <= offsets[0]) {
      this.deactivate();
      return;
    }

    if (scrollTop >= maxScroll) {
      return activeTarget != (i = targets.last()[0]) && this.activate(i)
    }

    if (activeTarget && scrollTop <= offsets[0]) {
      return activeTarget != (i = targets[0]) && this.activate(i)
    }


  ScrollSpy.prototype.deactivate = function (target) {
    $(this.selector)
      .parent('.active')
      .removeClass('active');
    this.activeTarget = null;
  }
```